# Firebase Uncaught Error in onSnapshot: [FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.]

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a firestore listener on my app (onSnapshot), and when I created it I get the error

> Uncaught Error in onSnapshot: [FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient
> permissions.]

```
useEffect(() => {
    const { firebase } = props;

    // Realtime database listene
    const unsuscribe = firebase
      .getDatabase()
      .collection("posts")
      .doc(firebase.getCurrentUser().uid)
      .collection("userPosts")
      .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
        let changes = snapshot.docChanges();
        changes.forEach((change) => {
          if (change.type === "added") {
            console.log(change.doc.data());
            // TODO - Add the new post to the posts list
          }
        });
      });

    return () => {
      // Detach the listening agent
      unsuscribe();
    };
  }, []);
```

I have been checking my permissions but it seems to be good:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    function isSignedIn() {
      return request.auth.uid != null;
    }
    
    function isSameUser(userId) {
        return request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
   
    match /posts/{userId}/userPosts {
       allow read: if true;
       allow write, update, delete: if isSignedIn() && isSameUser(userId);
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, the document (in /posts/{userId}/userPosts) that represents a user post will only be created if the user is signed in and if is the same user... Any ideas about what is wrong here?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okey I have the solution. I write it here because it might be useful for someone in the future.

Just do:

```
match /posts/{userId}/userPosts/{document=**} {
   allow read: if true;
   allow write, update, delete: if isSignedIn() && isSameUser(userId);
}
```

and will work fine.